# VS 2017 + cmake + ninja + mingw

Tags: c, visual-studio, build-process, mingw

I'm using VS 2017's new "open folder" feature with automatic cmake builds via CmakeSettings.json.

The code is written in C11, so I need to compile it with gcc (from mingw-64). I created a new cmake configuration that looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "GNU-Debug",
  "generator": "Ninja",
  "configurationType": "Debug",
  "inheritEnvironments": [ "msvc_x64_x64" ],
  "buildRoot": "${env.USERPROFILE}\\CMakeBuilds\\${workspaceHash}\\build\\${name}",
  "installRoot": "${env.USERPROFILE}\\CMakeBuilds\\${workspaceHash}\\install\\${name}",
  "variables": [
    {
      "name": "CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM",
      "value": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\mingw32-make.exe"
    },
    {
      "name": "CMAKE_C_COMPILER",
      "value": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe"
    },
    {
      "name": "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER",
      "value": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
    }
  ]
}
```

The output looks like this:

> The detected version of Ninja (GNU Make 4.2.1 Built for x86_64-w64-mingw32  Copyright (C) 1988-2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.  License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later  http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html  This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.  There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.) is less than the  version of Ninja required by CMake (1.3).

Which is very weird, considering the detected version of ninja is supposed to be a number. Both VS' ninja and MinGW ninja are up to date (1.8.2).

Is there any other way to have MinGW + CMake working inside VS 2017?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had to restart VS... Everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, compiling in a completely different environment (Yocto & Linux), but I suspect the root cause is the same. Maybe this will help someone out there.

It turned out CMake was getting invoked like this:

```
cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=make -G 'Ninja' ...
```

The Ninja generator was getting selected, but the wrong 'MAKE_PROGRAM' was getting set.

Should be:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=ninja -G 'Ninja' ...
```